# Image is flashing when updated new position

Tags: c#, timer, paint, paintevent

I have 2 picture objects.
I want both of them to move from right to left.
If one go out of the visible panel, I replace its position to the start point.
So there are always 2 pictures moving on the screen.

If I don't use timer, 2 pictures are painted. But if I use a timer with tick event updating their positions to make them move, there is only 1 picture is shown and it's keep flashing, lagging...

Below is my code so far. I'm not familiar with C#. Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Timer interval = 30;
Form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Background bg1 = new Background();
    Background bg2 = new Background(800);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void flowLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        bg1.paint(e);
        bg2.paint(e);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bg1.updatePosition();
        bg2.updatePosition();

        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Background:

```
class Background
{
    int bg_width = 800;
    int bg_height = 500;

    Image bg;
    Rectangle wb;
    private static int x = 0;

    public Background()
    {
        bg = Properties.Resources.bg;
        wb = new Rectangle(x, 0, bg_width, bg_height);
    }

    public Background(int custom_x)
    {
        x = custom_x;
        bg = Properties.Resources.bg;
        wb = new Rectangle(x, 0, bg_width, bg_height);
    }

    public void paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawImage(bg, wb);
    }

    public void updatePosition()
    {
        x--;
        if (x == -800)
        {
            x = 801;
        }
        wb.Location = new Point(x, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your timer interval is 0.03 second, Is it what you really want?

Comment: Double buffering FTW!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Explain what your _pictures_ actually are!